# Can not add collected email to Mailchimp list using Nodejs and express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am new to Nodejs and backend development. I am trying to build a email signup list page, where user enter their first name, last name and email. In my html file the input is called firstName, lastName and email consecutively. When user enters that data  the code below is supposed to save it to Mailchimp server audience list. It is my first time using Mailchimp. Can anyone tell me why this code bellow is not adding the collected data to the Mailchimp audience list?

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')
const https = require('https');
const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  //res.send("Server is up and running at port 3000");
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const email = req.body.email;

  const data = {
    members: [{
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: firstName,
        LNAME: lastName
      }
    }]
  }

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{List ID}";
  const options = {
    mathod: "POST",
    auth: "joy1:myapikey"
  }

  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
  console.log("Listening to port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a typo here. Also, when you make a post request, I am unable to see this API reference in their documentation. Check [here](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/exports/), you might be using a wrong API call.

```
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{List ID}";
  const options = {
    method: "POST", // here
    auth: "joy1:myapikey"
  }
```

Comment: It was the typo causing it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem as a beginner and found this post. I understand that code and ran it in my terminal.

```
                          **The solution is simple.**
```

**(1)** change **[extended: false]** to **[extended: true]**

```js
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

**(2)** change  **[mathod: "POST"]** to  **[method: "POST"]**

```js
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: "joy1:myapikey"
  }
```

**And at last, full code which worked for me:**

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')
const https = require('https');
const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  //res.send("Server is up and running at port 3000");
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/singup.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const firstName = req.body.fName;
  const lastName = req.body.lName;
  const email = req.body.email;

  const data = {
    members: [{
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: firstName,
        LNAME: lastName
      }
    }]
  }

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{List ID}"
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: "joy1:myapikey"
  }

  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
  console.log("Listening to port 3000");
});
```

Comment: You need to do all that to fix a single typo? The problem was caused by a typo, as the OP acknowledged.